# Can't understand the logic behind output of java program involving static objects

Tags: java, static

I am reading about static keyword. I tried a program involving static objects.
The output differs according from the concept. I don't understand why I am not getting a20 in output. Though both a1 and b1 are there on the console but not a20.
And why I am getting a1 twice in the output?

```
package j1;

class a {
    a(int i) {
       System.out.println("a"+1);
    }
}

class b {
    b(int i) {
        System.out.println("b"+1);
    }
}

class c {
    static a a1=new a(1);
    static b b1=new b(1);
    c() {
        System.out.println("c()");
    }
    static a a2=new a(20);
}

public class Static {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new c();
    }
}


//output:
a1
b1
a1
c()
```

Comment: sorry for that typing mistake!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's just a typo. You are printing a literal instead of argument `i`.

```
System.out.println("a"+1);
```

That should be

```
System.out.println("a"+i);
```

Comment: How can i delete this question??

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor for a is

```
a(int i){
    System.out.println("a"+1);
}
```

it can only print "a1", if you wish to print "a20", you'll need to incorporate the argument i into the output.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should help:

```
void a(int i) {
    System.out.println("a" + i);
}
```